# Why xslt cannot remove the <sMessage> node

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my filter:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xsl:template match="Table1/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Table1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xs:schema">
</xsl:template >
<xsl:template match="sMessage">
</xsl:template >
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my XML:

```
 <GetWorkOrderListResponse xmlns="http://buildfolio.com/TamesWebSvs/">
     <GetWorkOrderListResult>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
           <NewDataSet xmlns="">
              <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <WR_ID>862</WR_ID>
                 <WR_NO>RP-WO302</WR_NO>
              </Table1>
              <Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <WR_ID>722</WR_ID>
                 <WR_NO>TT12012-WO263</WR_NO>
              </Table1>
           </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
     </GetWorkOrderListResult>
    <sMessage>Download Success!</sMessage>
  </GetWorkOrderListResponse>
```

I am not able to remove the sMessage node from the output.  My output contains the text Download Success!, which I am trying to get rid of.   What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that your XML document has a default namespace:

```
xmlns="http://buildfolio.com/TamesWebSvs/"
```

By scoped inheritance, the sMessage element is in that namespace. To match it, you need to tell the match to look for sMessage in that namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="tws:sMessage" xmlns:tws="http://buildfolio.com/TamesWebSvs/">
```